# Resize a rectangle in Oxyplot

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, charts, plot

I am using [OxyPlot](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/) to plot some data. I want some mouse interaction with the plotted items.

I want to re-size the rectangles in `RectangleBarSeries`. Something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1).

I am unable to figure out the approach to proceed.

I have created a [sample application](http://www.speedyshare.com/3cJzQ/OxyResizeTesting.zip) that enable drag and dropping of rectangular I want to move the element when I click in center of rectangle item (as currently done). And want to re-size by clicking on corners as discussed in the code project link.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have implemented the same like [this](http://www.2shared.com/file/PMqHDC8g/OxyResizeTesting.html).